# Tools to investigate unusual algebraic structure

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory, category-theory, soft-question, projective-geometry

I will begin with a mostly motivational thought about the [projective plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plane). In this plane, every two lines intersect at a singular point. Let's mark the lines set as $\mathcal{L}$ and the points set as $\mathcal{P}$.

So you can think of two binary operations as follows:
$f_1: \mathcal{P}^2 \rightarrow \mathcal{L}$
and
$f_2: \mathcal{L}^2 \rightarrow \mathcal{P}$.

Where $f_1$ takes some 2 points and returns the line that passes through both and $f_2$ takes 2 lines and returns the intersection. This works well, partially due to the [duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(projective_geometry)) between points and lines. (Edit: In this example, we must use $f_1$ and $f_2$ as partial functions without pairs of the same point. It may also be possible to give some arbitrary line that goes through the point/ point on the line.)

This made me think about a generalization for some collection of $m$ sets $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^m$. Where between some of them there is some binary operation(/maybe partial without duplicate elements). A way to think about that is by putting the sets in some directed graph where there is a binary operation between neighboring sets.

This made me think that almost everything I know of in algebra includes a set with a *closed* operation. My questions are the following:

1. Is it a known structure or some far-fetched idea?

   a. Are there any known algebraic structures with more than one set? (like the given example of the projective plane)
2. Can this be reduced to a classic single-set structure?
3. What tools are there when encountering some unknown/exotic algebraic structure?

(I added the tag of category theory because I thought it may be related, but I neither see any way to use it nor am proficient enough in the subject)

Comment: Your "operations" are not well defined because you do not say how to deal with the case when the two points are the same point, or when two lines are the same line. You need to explain what to do in that case, or else take $f_1$ and $f_2$ to be *partial* functions.

Comment: You are right, this doesn't work without partial function(/maybe a special case where you give some arbitrary result), I fixed it in the question. Nevertheless, this question still holds and the example is mostly for motivation.

Comment: Two binary operations does not really an algebraic structure make.  Usually it requires some interplay between the two operations.

Comment: If it were me, I would fix a point $p$ and a line $L$ and consider the maps that these binary operations make from $\mathcal P\setminus \{p\}\to \mathcal L$ and $\mathcal L\setminus \{L\}\to \mathcal P$.  The first one could be described as "the pencil of lines through $p$" and the second one I guess is just "the points on $L$."  Depending on the incidence relation of $p$ and $L$ you might say something interesting.

Comment: @rschwieb Yeah, that sounds pretty legit. But I must note again that this was more of a motivational section and my main wonder is about the usage(/tools to dissect) of algebraic structures of this type. (where there is more than a single set with operations)

Comment: Maybe "multisorted logic" is applicable here?  (Another example of multisorted logic is where you want to talk about a theory where a model is a generic ring $R$ together with a generic left $R$-module $M$.)